# How to call a method from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to figure out how to take the
`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` 
, method and call it from another view controller.

In **LocationViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  //save bar button item
  UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Save" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(saveButtonPressed)];

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

  [self performSelector:@selector(saveButtonPressed) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
}

-(void)saveButtonPressed {

    //I want to call the method here

}
```

In **GameDetailsTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer1 = @"GameDetailsLocationCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer1];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello world"

    return cell;
}
```

I am a beginner in IOS and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: It's part of a different project I am working on

Comment: Create an Object of another controller and call the method.

Comment: It's not really advisable to call cellForRow at anytime, let alone from another controller. Do you need to access the cell for something or just want to reload it?

Comment: i just want to reload it

Comment: Then you can either reload the table view rather than calling cellForRow. Make a instance of the table view and call reloadData. @av993

Comment: I tried, unfortunately its not working

Comment: @av993 Can you post your updated code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you can trigger the datasource methods of tableview from another class. Heres how

Suppose you want to trigger `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of Class A from Class B's method `someMethod`

In Class A.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(somemethodToReloadtableview) name:@"NOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil];
}
//Implement the method
-(void)somemethodToReloadtableview{
[self.customTableViewName reloadData];
}
```

Class B.m

```
-(void)methodFromWhichYouWantToTrigger{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil];
}
```

P.S - This method will invoke all the datasource of tableview such as `numberOfRows`.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to call the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` manually. If you want your table view to reload the data, you can call `reloadData` method on your table view.

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

And if you want to trigger this from another view controller, you can post a notification from the other view controller and listen to that from the one where table view exists. Saheb's answer describes how to post the notification and listen to that.

Comment: What additional information does your answer have over saheb's answer?

Comment: It doesn't provide any extra information. But, it provides clarity. If you feel, it's unnecessary answer, you can delete it!!